# How to make my canvas2d game faster?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm working on a html5 canvas2d game. As complicated the game is, the FPS count is lower and lower.
I don't use images in my scenes. So are there any tricks, or practices to increase FPS?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: While I think this could be a really interesting discussion, you're probably going to have to give some specifics about how you're using the canvas and where your bottlenecks are in order to get an answer here.  Are you using any libraries or just HTML5 & Javascript?

Comment: ahhh frames per second depends upon the structure of the game and depends upon the computer on which it is being played

Answer (score 2):

First step is profiling your game. You find a good tutorial here: http://nicolahibbert.com/optimising-html5-canvas-games/ with some must-do rules for html games optimization.

Answer (score 2):

Although your question isn't quite specific, I made improvements in my canvas apps/games by using multiple canvases positioned on top of each other.
This way, you can avoid unnecessary repaints of unchanged parts of the canvas.

Say you have 20 players in your game. If one of them moves, you should update only it's layer (it's own canvas) instead of updating the whole picture.

This is the technique used by many canvas libraries including [kinetick.js](http://kineticjs.com/) and it really improves the speed of your app.

Also, you should sync your game loop with the browser's repaint events: use [request animation frame](http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating) instead of the plain-ol' `setinterval`.

Answer (score -1):

There are many things you can do to optimising your game. Often, it's just lots of little improvements that can make a difference.

Some things to be aware of

- **Use multiple canvases (as already mentioned)**
- **Garbage collection**: The JS garbage collection can really make your game choppy. This is  a subject in itself but one thing you can do is limit the creation of objects as much as possible and re-use your objects.

Example

```
// This...
test = [];

// ...Is better than this
test = new array()
```

- **Loops**: You can speed up your loops by using reverse while loops, like so:

EG

```
var i = nodes.length();
while (i--) {
    // ...do stuff...
}
```

- **Object nesting**: Don't nest objects more than 3 levels deep, if possible. It takes JS awhile to locate them.
- **Draws**: DrawImage is expensive. Use sparingly.